# Css & Asp:Button conflict

Tags: asp.net, css, aspbutton

I am working on a webpage and at  some point I need to disable a asp:button.

This page uses a css file that has the following class:

```
.pagerLinkDisabled
{
    display: none;
}
```

So every time I set a button to disabled .net renders it with `class="pagerLinkDisabled"` and the button is not displayed...

At pageload I tried this:

```
myButton.Enabled=false;
myButton.Style.Add("display","static");
```

How can I work around this problem without changing the css file?

Thanks :)

**Edit**:

To clarify:

- The button is being rendered but when enabled is set to false the framework is adding class="pagerLinkDisabled" to the input tag.
- This class is defined at a css file that I cannot change.

**Edit2:**

My button is defined as such:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="myButton" Text="mytext" Enabled="false" />
```

The html that is being rendered is:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$myButton" value="mytext" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_myButton" class="pagerLinkDisabled" />
```

Comment: What problem?  You haven't explained the observed behavior vs the expected behavior very well.

Comment: "static" is not a valid display value - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop

Comment: As David mentioned, "static" is a valid value for the "position" property, and not the "display" property. See <a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position">CSS2, Visual, 9.3.1</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just edit the **HTML Source** so that the button does not use that class?

Or is it defines at a higher level within with HTML? e.g. At the BODY tag.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but try at page load:

```
myButton.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Nice try but no...  when visible = false the button is not rendered, in this case it is being rendered but being keep "unvisible" with the display:none from the css

Answer (score 1):

Why not just change the class name on the button?

Comment: Also tried that. If I define a cssclass for the button the input tag is rendered with the class attributes and assumes the first one..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
myButton.Attributes.Add("Style","display:block !important");
```

Comment: Doing that makes the button appear, but enabled... I have placed the line just bellow myButton.Enabled = false

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** This works for me.

```
myButton.Style["display"] = "block !important";
myButton.Style["disabled"] = "disabled";
```

Comment: Check for the update, it works for me.  I would prefer to just update the CSSClass attribute on the button if at all possible though.

Comment: Then something else is going on we can't see.  Does your input element have the disabled='disabled' attribute? Something else must be conflicting, even the single lb.Style["display"] = "block !important"; works fine on a blank page with a single CSS class defined.  Add what the markup is putting to the question and I might be able to help more.

Comment: I'm not sure what framework you are working with.  ASP does not add that CSS Class by default, maybe something else is conflicting with it.